# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: In Rest Webservice After HTTP URL Connection, after adding Certificate as well

Tags: java, rest, ssl, exception

I have a REST application web-service deployed, At client side, after framing URL, I am making a HTTP URL Connection & opened Buffered Reader to send the data stream towards server side.

Here is the snippet of code..

```
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(
         new javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier(){

              public boolean verify(String hostname,
                      javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession) {
                  return true;
              }
        });

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) tnprestapplicationURL.openConnection();
String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
```

I have added a certificate as it makes SSL Connection. I don't know this concept. Below is the piece of code i have added to get rid of the exception, but still i face below exception. Can anyone help on this?

```
Final Url is  https://10.53.108.123:8443/tnpWS/webapi/tnp/getAlerts?exportCustomFields=Severity,KPI,Dimension,Referencevalue,KPIvalue,Starttime,Endtime,Notificationstatus|PERCEIVED_SEVERITY,PI_NAME,PI_DIM_VALUE,THRESHOLD_VALUE,OBSERVED_VALUE,from_unixtime(CAST(PI_START_TIME/1000asBIGINT))PI_START_TIME,from_unixtime(CAST(PI_END_TIME/1000asBIGINT))PI_END_TIME,PI_NOTIFY_STATUS&startDate=29-10-2017%2014:00:00&queryType=getAlerts&severity=&endDate=29-10-2017%2016:41:06&exportDB=false&exportFields=&exportFileName=&
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1914)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:279)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:273)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1477)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:213)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:961)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:897)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1033)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1342)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1369)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1353)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1348)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
        at com.nokia.tnp.alertmonitor.actions.AlertMonitorActionController.getData(AlertMonitorActionController.java:165)
```

Comment: Certificates are bound to _host names_, not IP addresses. Change your configuration. Replace `10.53.108.123` by a valid host name that is your certificates  'Common Name' or is part of 'Subject Alternative Names'. And configure DNS appropriate.

Comment: That final URL is the URL to which i need submit HTTP GET request. While adding certificate, i have added through the key tool utility. And in the SSLContext code, i have used hostname only.

Comment: @blafasel: that's wrong. RFC 2818 (and 5280) specifically allows iPAddress in SAN. (6125 discourages it but does not prohibit it and doesn't apply to HTTPS anyway.) And although not specified AFAIK, in practice nearly everybody accepts IP in CN and did so before SAN support became widespread, although Java's default verifier for HttpsURL does not since j6 at least. A public CA (at least a CABforum member) won't give you a cert for a _private_ address like 10/8, but they won't give you a cert for a private DNS name like `.local` or `.site` either.

Comment: Dheeraj: your problem is indeed the cert, not the name. (The default name verifier would fail, as I just noted, but you have overridden it.) You create an `SSLContext` but don't customize it _or_ use it for anything in the code shown. Do you have system properties `javax.net.ssl.trustStore*` set on JVM startup or in your code before the first SSL/TLS connection occurs? Is the cert you are using selfsigned? (Note that doesn't just mean signed by _you_, it means signed using the same _key_ and having Subject=Issuer.) If j7+ show us `keytool -printcert -sslserver 10.53.108.123:8443`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Yes, i am not doing anything with SSLContext Object, certificate is signed with the server IP which i am trying to access. I am able to print with "keytool -printcert -sslserver 10.53.108.123:8443"

Comment: A certificate is signed with a key; an IP address is not a key and cannot sign anything. The cert should _contain_ the server IP(s) or name(s), but that has nothing to do with signing. You are not providing the information that might solve the problem. Please _show_ (in your Q) the cert/chain info, and as I also said, whether the truststore is set to anything non-default.